# stepAIC function with tslm function in R

Tags: r

I wish to forecast a time series and so I use something like this :

Suppose I have a data `xtrain` with `V1,V2,V3,V4` as the attributes. Then I will create a model as follows:

```
form=as.formula(train ~ trend + season + V1 + V2 + V3 + V4)

mod = tslm(form,data=xtrain)
```

And now I wish to use `stepAIC`,

```
step = stepAIC(mod, direction = "both", trace = F)
```

but here, I get an error like:

```
Error in [.default (x, , jj, drop = FALSE) : incorrect number of dimensions
```

How should `stepAIC` be used with `tslm` function?